# Nameof expression with switch

Tags: c#

I am comparing the values coming from command argument with switch case condition
but it always goes to default case.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
        if (args!=null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            switch (args[0])
            {
                case nameof(appSettings.KeyName1):
                    //Do some stuff related to keyName1
                    break;
                case nameof(appSettings.KeyName2):
                    //Do some stuff related to KeyName2
                    break;
                case nameof(appSettings.KeyName3):
                    //Do some stuff related to keyName3
                    break;

                default:
                    //do default if there is no match
                    break;
            }

        }
```

AppConfig.cs File Code

```
  class AppSettings
{
    public string KeyName1 { get; set; }
    public string KeyName2 { get; set; }
    public string KeyName3 { get; set; }

    public AppSettings()
    {
        GetValueFromConfigFile();
    }

    public void GetValueFromConfigFile()
    {
        KeyName1 = GetKeyByValue("KeyName1");
        KeyName2 = GetKeyByValue("KeyName2");
        KeyName3 = GetKeyByValue("KeyName3");
    }
    public string GetKeyByValue(string _keyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_keyName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key Name cannot be null");
        }
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_keyName];
    
    }
}
```

Configuration file

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="KeyName1" value="Key1Value"/>
<add key="KeyName2" value="Key2Value"/>
<add key="KeyName3" value="Key3Value"/>
</appSettings>
```

**Runtime values** [image]
I want to check if coming argument passed by user is matching with the key value using switch case.

Thank You!!

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what all the relevant values are returning?

Comment: Args is just a comma delimited string. You should be able to foreach through the string array, or check args[0], args[1], be etc.

Comment: @JayBuckman AppSettings is call which contains logic to read the values from app.config file and than assign to properties.

Comment: Yes @Anu6is values are same in quickwatch but switch is not recognizing it

Comment: `nameof` is less powerful than you may assume. Do you expect `args[0]` to possibly be `KeyName1` or `Key1Value` ?

Comment: Can you show us how are you passing the arguments to the app? This code is working just fine if you pass args properly.

Comment: @msmolcic I have updated the question please see the runtime what I am getting

Comment: @VirenderThakur well, the issue is obvious from that screenshot, you have "Key2Value" as an input argument and your switch cases are "KeyName1", "KeyName2", "KeyName3"... it doesn't match any case and ends up in default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the attached screenshot, the `args` param can contain a **value** and not a **key** of an `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` entry and you actually need to get the key of the passed value - if any - to execute different routines in the switch block accordingly. If I'm interpreting the problem here correctly, then you can get the key from the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys` collection whose value is the passed value.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
   if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
    {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings();
        var key = appSettings.TryGetKey(args[0]);

        switch (key)
        {
            case nameof(appSettings.KeyName1):
                //Do some stuff related to keyName1                        
                break;
            case nameof(appSettings.KeyName2):
                //Do some stuff related to KeyName2                        
                break;
            case nameof(appSettings.KeyName3):
                //Do some stuff related to keyName3                        
                break;
            default:                        
                //do default if there is no match
                break;
        }
    }
}

class AppSettings
{
    public string KeyName1 { get; set; }
    public string KeyName2 { get; set; }
    public string KeyName3 { get; set; }

    public AppSettings()
    {
        GetValuesFromConfigFile();
    }

    public void GetValuesFromConfigFile()
    {
        KeyName1 = TryGetValue("KeyName1");
        KeyName2 = TryGetValue("KeyName2");
        KeyName3 = TryGetValue("KeyName3");
    }

    public string TryGetValue(string _key)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key Name cannot be null");
        }
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_key];
    }

    public string TryGetKey(string _value) =>
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Cast<string>()
        .FirstOrDefault(k => TryGetValue(k) == _value);
}
```

Note, I've changed the names to avoid confusion.